# Magento 2 Product Filter By Category & Multiple Product Attributes

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, ajax, filter

I'm currently building a custom product filter via Ajax. I've got the basics working but now I'm trying to filter via category and a specific product attribute.

Here is my code

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$categoryData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('whoisitfor');

// Get category selected.
if(isset($categoryData)) {
    $categoryData = $this->expandFormValues($categoryData);
    $categories = [$categoryData];//category ids array
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);
}
```

This get's the products for the specific categories that are selected on the frontend, this works fine.

Now when I try and filter it by a specific product attribute it still just returns all the products from the category above not the specific products with the attribute filtered on.

Here is the code:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('user_experience_level', array('eq' => 3003));
```

Full code looks like this:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$categoryData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('whoisitfor');

// Get category selected.
if(isset($categoryData)) {
    $categoryData = $this->expandFormValues($categoryData);
    $categories = [$categoryData];//category ids array
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);
}

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('user_experience_level', array('eq' => 3003));
```

If anyone can help me with this, it'd be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$categoryData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('whoisitfor');

// Get category selected.
if(isset($categoryData)) {
$categoryData = $this->expandFormValues($categoryData);
$categories = [$categoryData];//category ids array
$collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);

}

$collection->addFieldToFilter('user_experience_level', array('eq' => 3003));
```